# How to avoid div getting full page size if height is not set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm having a problem with my layout. I currently have a `display: none` and `position: fixed` div that shows up when you hit a button in the page. In this div there is a table of buttons for the user to pick.

The problem I'm having is that if I don't set a height for this window it becomes full page sized, it becomes full page-height. This is a problem for me since the button number is going to change and I won't be able to use a fixed height for each one of them.

I made some fiddles, the first one is the div with a height set: http://jsfiddle.net/gbRzt/
And the second one is without a height set: http://jsfiddle.net/gbRzt/1/

This is unrelated to the question, but it's also a problem I'm having. In the last row of buttons, the #7 and #8 aren't centered. Would there be any way to center them like the others?

Comment: Can you use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes ? Here's a playground http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a try, will edit this later if I get any success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of `top` and `bottom` on `.bankingDialog`, `position:  absolute;` is also a better option than `fixed` in this case.

```
.bankingDialog {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 1em;
    z-index: 200;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

#### An answer for your unrelated question:

Have a look at this <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gbRzt/3/)</kbd>. You are using paragraphs and a table while you don't need them. It's much easier to do what you want with `div`'s only.

**HTML**

```
<div class="bankingDialog" id="bankingWeaponsDialog">
    <div class="centerer">
        <div class="bankingbuttons">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="bankingbuttons">Bot #1</div>
        <div class="bankingbuttons">Bot #2</div>
        <div class="bankingbuttons">Bot #3</div>
        <div class="bankingbuttons">Bot #4</div>
        <div class="bankingbuttons">Bot #5</div>
        <div class="bankingbuttons">Bot #6</div>
        <div class="bankingbuttons">Bot #7</div>
        <div class="bankingbuttons">Bot #8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bankingDialog {
    text-align: center;
}
.centerer {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.bankingDialog .bankingbuttons:first-child {
    display: block;
}
.bankingDialog .bankingbuttons {
    display: inline-block;
}
.bankingDialog2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: yes, bottom is 0 and top is 0 too so it will become 100% height

Comment: Mmm, just removing the top and bottom worked, thanks! The problem now is that, since I don't have a fixed height, I can't center the div on the page. Is there any way to use `margin: auto` without having to set a height? (By the way, I'm using `position: fixed` just because I need the div to scroll with the mouse)

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the need for a scrollable container.

Comment: I have added an answer for your "unrelated question".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[image: bankingDialog2 css class]

[image: bankingDialog css class]

Will produce this:
[image: Result]

Note if you want both the `div#rightCol` and `div.bankingDialog` to be aligned left and avoid `div.bankingDialog` to be over `div#rightCol`, you might give `div.bankingDialog` a `margin-left` of `div#rightCol`'s width. Or place the `div#rightCol` and `div.bankingDialog` in the same level and do both `float: left`.

EDIT: if you want any container to be scrollable you could do this:

http://jsbin.com/anixeq/1/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! And the `.bankingDialog` is supposed to be over `#rightCol`, there in the fiddle it wasn't much visible though. The problem I was having was because of top and bottom. Now I just got to figure out how to center the last row of buttons.